# Adding text annotation to a clustering scatter plot (tSNE)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, scatter-plot, ggrepel

I have `XY` data (a 2D `tSNE` embedding of high dimensional data) which I'd like to `scatter plot`. The data are assigned to several `cluster`s, so I'd like to color code the points by `cluster` and then add a single label for each `cluster`, that has the same color coding as the `cluster`s, and is located outside (as much as possible) from the `cluster`'s points.

Any idea how to do this using `R` in either `ggplot2` and `ggrepel` or `plotly`?

Here's the example data (the `XY` coordinates and `cluster` assignments are in `df` and the labels in `label.df`) and the `ggplot2` part of it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(1,20,4),function(i) data.frame(x=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),y=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),cluster=i)))
df$cluster <- factor(df$cluster)

label.df <- data.frame(cluster=levels(df$cluster),label=paste0("cluster: ",levels(df$cluster)))

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=cluster))+geom_point()+theme_minimal()+theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `geom_label_repel()` function in the `ggrepel` package allows you to easily add labels to plots while trying to "repel" the labels from not overlapping with other elements. A slight addition to your existing code where we summarize the data / get coordinates of where to put the labels (here I chose the upper left'ish region of each cluster - which is the min of x and the max of y) and merge it with your existing data containing the cluster labels. Specify this data frame in the call to `geom_label_repel()` and specify the variable that contains the `label` aesthetic in `aes()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(1,20,4),function(i) data.frame(x=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),y=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),cluster=i)))
df$cluster <- factor(df$cluster)

label.df <- data.frame(cluster=levels(df$cluster),label=paste0("cluster: ",levels(df$cluster)))
label.df_2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>% 
  summarize(x = min(x), y = max(y)) %>% 
  left_join(label.df)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,color=cluster))+geom_point()+theme_minimal()+theme(legend.position="none") +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = label.df_2, aes(label = label))
```

[image: Output]